# regex match equal with tilde Vs double equal sign

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, opensips

Its wired question but i want to know what is the difference between `=~` and `==`

Following "string" i am trying to find.

```
if($ua =~ "friendly-scanner") {
  drop()
}
```

Vs

```
if($ua == "friendly-scanner") {
  drop()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=~ - Does a regular expression matching
== - Compares two for equality
```

For example:

```
if($ua =~ "^friendly") is "$ua begins with friendly"
if($ua == "friendly") is "$ua exact match with friendly"
```